# Different directories using different PHP versions?

Tags: php, drupal-8, acquia

I have installed the Acquia Developer Desktop on Windows 7.

I need to install Lightning so I've tried to update Composer and Drupal to the latest versions so I can install Lightning correctly.

I specified PHP 5.6.19 when creating a new site in Aquia Developer Desktop.

When I try to upgrade, I get errors about PHP version. When I run php -v in the site directory, it reports as 5.4.45. When I run it in the Dev Desktop directory, it reports as 5.5.33.

I have seen a number of threads for OSX or Linux environments but I cannot match them to the Windows environment.

How can I ensure the site is running on 5.5 or later?

This is in my httpd.conf:

```
 <IfDefine !php_fcgi>
  <IfDefine php5_3>
    LoadModule php5_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_3\php5apache2_4.dll"
    PHPINIDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_3"
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine php5_4>
    LoadModule php5_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_4\php5apache2_4.dll"
    PHPINIDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_4"
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine php5_5>
    LoadModule php5_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_5\php5apache2_4.dll"
    PHPINIDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_5"
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine php5_6>
    LoadModule php5_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_6\php5apache2_4.dll"
    PHPINIDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_6"
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine php7_0>
    LoadModule php7_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php7_0\php7apache2_4.dll"
    PHPINIDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php7_0"
  </IfDefine>
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: According to Acquia's web site, the dev desktop includes PHP. So whatever version you or Lightning requires, you must install it in the web server, or wherever the web server's path is set.

Comment: I believe I have the right version installed. I think I may need to tell Apache and/or the site which version to target though? But I am not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at [`IfDefine`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#ifdefine)

> The parameter-name argument is a define as given on the httpd command line via -Dparameter at the time the server was started or by the Define directive.

So, you can either start Apache with an additional command line argument

```
-Dphp5_5
```

or insert a [`Define`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#define) directive before the given section

```
Define php5_5
```

The same, if you want to use PHP 5.6 (`php5_6`) or 7.0 (`php7_0`).